# Calculate Average Color from a SVG Image (SvgPicture.network(""))

Tags: flutter, svg, colors

I try to calculate the average color from SVG format Image, but I don't know how can **an SVG Image from the network** convert to `Unit8List`, `ImageProvider`, or `BitMap`!
for any of these types that I say, I can calculate the average color with the below code :

(I use [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image))

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imgPack;
//
Unit8List _myHunit8List =  ...
imgPack.Image bitmap = imgPack.decodeImage(_myHunit8List );

  int redBucket = 0;
  int greenBucket = 0;
  int blueBucket = 0;
  int pixelCount = 0;

  for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.width; x++) {
      int c = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

      pixelCount++;
      redBucket += img.getRed(c);
      greenBucket += img.getGreen(c);
      blueBucket += img.getBlue(c);
    }
  }

  Color averageColor = Color.fromRGBO(redBucket ~/ pixelCount,
      greenBucket ~/ pixelCount, blueBucket ~/ pixelCount, 1);
```

---

how can I an SVG Image from the network

( I use [flutter_svg package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) like:

```
SvgPicture.network(url);
```

) convert to `Unit8List` ?

Comment: I would use canvas for this. Canvas is allowing you to loop all the pixels in an image and retrive the red green blue and alpha values for every pixel. If you must you can draw an svg image onto the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

It transfers from Image url to Uint8List.

```
Future<Uint8List> getUint8ListFromImage(imgUrl) async {
    Uint8List bytes = (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(imgUrl)).load(imgUrl))
        .buffer
        .asUint8List();
    print(bytes);
    return bytes;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert `network image` to `file` and then you can easily convert `file` to `uint8List`,

convert image url to file

```
Future<File> urlToFile(String imageUrl) async {
// generate random number.
var rng = new Random();
// get temporary directory of device.
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
// get temporary path from temporary directory.
String tempPath = tempDir.path;
// create a new file in temporary path with random file name.
File file = new File('$tempPath'+ (rng.nextInt(100)).toString() +'.svg');
// call http.get method and pass imageUrl into it to get response.
http.Response response = await http.get(imageUrl);
// write bodyBytes received in response to file.
await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
// now return the file which is created with random name in 
// temporary directory and image bytes from response is written to // that file.
return file;
}
```